# Picard Lindelöf

Tags: real-analysis

I have this question I wanna solve. Any help. I think I have to use Picard-Lindelöf to solve it, but I don't know how.

> Suppose that $0\le c<1,$ and $f_1:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f_2:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ are functions such that, for every $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2,$
>   $$|f_1(x_1,y_1)-f_1(x_2,y_2)|\le c|x_1-x_2| $$
>   and
>   $$|f_2(x_1,y_1)-f_2(x_2,y_2)|\le c|y_1-y_2|. $$
>   Prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
>   $$f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y))$$
>   has a unique fixed point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I denote the euclidic norm on $ \mathbb R^2$ by $|| \cdot||$. Then we get

$||f(x,y)-f(u,v)||^2$

$=(f_1(x,y)-f_1(u,v))^2 +(f_2(x,y)-f_2(u,v))^2$

$ \le c^2(x-u)^2+c^2(y-v)^2=c^2||(x,y)-(u,v)||^2$,

hence

$||f(x,y)-f(u,v)|| \le c ||(x,y)-(u,v)||$.

Since $0 \le c <1$, the function $f$ is a contraction. By Banach, $f$ has a unique fixed point.

Picard - Lindelöf ??? No ! Banach !